child component with tabs not getting correct ID - ionic/angular
I am new to ionic, and I am trying to design a simple app to learn. I have a main page (MP), and when i click on a button on that page, I get forwarded to a new page (AP) and I have tabs. My tabs has two buttons. First button would just show that page I just got redirected to (AP). The other button goes to another page (BP) some more content associated with the first one.
this is my route:
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('./main/main.page.component').then((m) => m.MainPage),
  },
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'book/:id', // dynamic route for story details
        loadComponent: () =>
          import('./story/story.component').then((m) => m.StoryComponent),
      },
      {
        path: 'review/:id',
        loadComponent: () =>
          import('./practice/practice.component').then((m) => m.PracticeComponent),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/main',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
    ],
  },
];

This is my tabs page:
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button [href]="getBookTabHref()">
      <ion-icon aria-hidden="true" name="book-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Book</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button [href]="getReviewTabHref()">
      <ion-icon name="square"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Review</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>

So from my main page I go to Book just fine, and I shows the correct ID. But when, from there, I try to use the tabs buttons, it does not have the ID state.
I have tried a few things with the help of chatgpt, like
activeRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
  this.id = params['id'];
  console.log('subscribe (after navigation end)', this.id);
});, 

but nothing works and my ID is lost.
What is the best practice and how do I retain that state in an app?
I come from a web world, so this concept is a bit strange to me..
thanks!

What is getReviewTabHref() and getBookTabHref() doing? The link is maybe wrong.

basically getBookTabHref() {
return /tabs/book/${this.id};
} But the id is undefined as it is not getting to the component

The params must be subscribed within the component specified in the route. Subscription is therefore only possible in the StoryComponent or PracticeComponent. The TabsPage has no id parameter in the route.

so how can i get the id? should I do something like tabs/id/book/id?

Why you can't get the ID parameter
The parameters must be read in the component that the route points to. The route 'tabs' has no ID parameter. The parameter must be read in the component StoryComponent or PracticeComponent.
Solution 1: Use query parameters
Adjust the URL so that the ID is specified as a query parameter:
/tabs/book?id=123
Then the ID can be read as follows:
this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
  this.id = params['id'];
});

Solution 2: Specify the ID in the tabs route
Adjust your route as follows:
/tabs/123/book
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadComponent: () =>
      import('./main/main.page.component').then((m) => m.MainPage),
  },
  {
    path: 'tabs/:id', // <= id param here
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'book', // dynamic route for story details
        loadComponent: () =>
          import('./story/story.component').then((m) => m.StoryComponent),
      },
      {
        path: 'review',
        loadComponent: () =>
          import('./practice/practice.component').then((m) => m.PracticeComponent),
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/main',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
    ],
  },
];

The ID can then be read in the TabsPage as follows:
this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
  this.id = params['id'];
});

The ID can then be read in the child routes as follows:
this.route.parent?.params.subscribe((params) => {
  const id = params['id'];
})


so for me the best solution seems to be 2, but unfortunately when i do that and navigate to tabs/1/book and try to get the ID based on the parent like you suggested, this.route.parent is always null

I created a working project using this code: stackblitz

thanks, rico! I noticed the project in stackblitz is using angular, not an ionic one. I wonder if maybe that plays a role. because i tried the same thing on my local being ionic and it does not get the id correvtly :(
